# Angular : Access component variable in css file

Tags: css, angular

Here is my css file and I'm trying to do like this :

```
.login-wrapper {
  background-image: url({{imagePath}});
}
```

My component:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  imagePath: any = 'assets/discord-logo.png';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

It doesn't work.

How can I do to inject the 'imagePath' from my component to the css file ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can apply inline css in html file like this:

```
<div class="div"  [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+imageUrl+')'">
</div>
```

demo link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1rf1tl?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes but I didn't want to write css in html , so it is impossible to not pass by the html ?

Comment: @Bilal if you want to give dynamic image in background you have to give it inline css & it's the ideal way of binding dynamic images..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle to add the background image in HTML file like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(&quot;' + imagePath + '&quot;)'}" > </div>
```

Comment: Yes but I didn't want to write css in html , so it is impossible to not pass by the html ?

Comment: you can't access angular/js variables in CSS.